# linear programming constraint for conditional

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I having formulating the following (what should be fairly simple) ilp constraint. Basically let $p$ be a binary variable and $s$ be an integer that is greater than or equal to 0.

The constraint is simply:

if(p==1) then s=0.

I do not care what s is when p is 0. Any ideas or resources to check? I feel like this shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowing that $s \ge 0$, I think you'd better take $s \le M\, (1-p)$, where $M$ is a large enough  value. When $p=1$, then $s=0$. Is $p=0$, than $s$ can be any value between $0$ and $M$.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for. I would upvote if I could.